# How to mention from string on discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

i'm setting up a dicord bot i have usernames on a database so i get the user name ftrom a method that connects to database and return username in a string what i want is to mention from that string i can't get ir to work

i've tried searching on documentaton but i didnt understood it at all

```
async def job(channelid,message):
    print('init schedule')
    channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
    current_apps=current_app()
    usersapps=apps_user(current_apps["APPS"])
    counter=0
    while True:
        counter= counter + 1
        for i in range(0,len(usersapps)):
            await discord.client.send_message("{}".format(usersapps[i]['USER']),mentions=True)

        await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds
```

i excpect my code to mention the given user by the string that comes from my method

the error i'm getting

```
init schedule
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<job() done, defined at c:\Users\Nte\Desktop\rainbow army\bot.py:136> exception=TypeError("send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mentions'",)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Nte\Desktop\rainbow army\bot.py", line 145, in job
    await discord.client.send_message("{}".format(usersapps[i]['USER']),mentions=True)
TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mentions'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to mention a user by saving userid into database and then get it with my method and sending message like this

```
await channel.send("<@!{}>".format(usersapps[i]['USERID']))
```